# How to get Django model id in views.py

Tags: python, django

I know Django automatically create a unique id for every model created. For example like this

```
fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=50)),
                ('language', models.CharField(choices=[('ur-PK', 'Urdu'), ('en-US', 'English')], max_length=15)),
            ],
```

But I want to get this id in `views.py` file. How can I do this? I am using django model forms to enter data.

I tried this

```
request.POST['id']
```

But it throws an error
MultiValueDictKeyError at /
'id'

**EDIT**
Views.py code

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = uploadForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST['id'])
        lang=request.POST['language']
        if form.is_valid():
           #save form
```

Comment: can you provide your `view.py` code

Comment: You don't have to provide `Id` though it generated automatically for a newly created record so simply remove accessing ID code

Comment: I need it, I have an audio file recorded from the front end, that I want to save with this id. i want every audio file to be saved with unique name

Answer (score 1):

In request.POST you will not get id because the record is not saved yet. so do this way

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = uploadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           record = form.save()
           print(record.id) # this will print id
           print(record.language)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement it in urls.py, For example:

```
path('<id>/', RecordDetails.as_view(), name='record_details')
```

And as for your code, you can get it from the 'request' or 'kwargs', Example:

```
class RecordDetails(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        request_id = int(self.kwargs['id'])
        queryset = Model.objects.filter(id=request_id)
        return queryset
```